# Confusion about output layer activation function for multi-label classification

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I am doing mulit-label classification for tabular data with `fastai` (implemented using the multi-label helper in the `fastai` documentation) and the model is performing great! But, when I inspected the model further, I noticed that the output layer is nothing but a linear transformation rather than using a Sigmoid activation function. More specifically, the architecture is

```
TabularModel(
  (embeds): ModuleList(
    (0): Embedding(25, 10)
    (1): Embedding(9, 5)
    (2): Embedding(33, 11)
    (3): Embedding(32, 11)
    (4): Embedding(8, 5)
    (5): Embedding(207, 32)
    (6): Embedding(3, 3)
    (7): Embedding(3, 3)
    (8): Embedding(3, 3)
    (9): Embedding(3, 3)
    (10): Embedding(3, 3)
    (11): Embedding(3, 3)
    (12): Embedding(5, 4)
  )
  (emb_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
  (bn_cont): BatchNorm1d(314, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (layers): Sequential(
    (0): LinBnDrop(
      (0): BatchNorm1d(410, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (1): Linear(in_features=410, out_features=200, bias=False)
      (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
    (1): LinBnDrop(
      (0): BatchNorm1d(200, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (1): Linear(in_features=200, out_features=100, bias=False)
      (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
    (2): LinBnDrop(
      (0): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=4, bias=True)
    )
  )
)v
```

I noticed that Jason Brownlee wrote here that for multi-label classification the activation function for the output layer should be a `nn.Sigmoid()`. I tried replacing the last layer with a `LinBnDrop(act=nn.Sigmoid())` layer, but then I get no improvement in validation loss and worse performance overall.

Why is it that that tabular_model implements a linear output layer automatically for multi-label classification?

Comment: It would be difficult to pin-point on what could affect the performance without more details. But from the info provided, final layer generally don't have dropout/batch-norm applied.

Comment: @scarecrow I've removed the second question for now, because im more interested in the first bit. Is is common to implement a linear layer for multi-label classification? Shouldn't it be a sigmoid layer for this to even work?